# batch script for merging and inserting file before a particular text

Tags: batch-file

I still don't understand what makes you more confused here. Anyway I got solution for my first question. I am able to merge 2 files and able to insert the content in first file.

Now come up with a scenario where I'm trying to remove a specific string from file1 and copy file1 to file2.
Below my code

```
set file1=Y:\NAS\EODReport\\"CAT Channels Audit Report_%TODAY%**.TXT\"
FINDSTR  /V  "Transaction Gateway Item Listing Creation Amount Seq Y:" %file1%> file2.txt
```

In file2, i can see the file1 namee (`Y:\NAS\EODReport\\"CAT Channels Audit Report_%TODAY%**.TXT\`) is getting copied all over the line.

How can i remove that filename in my file2 content ?

Comment: What is the particular position of s1 ?

Comment: Do you want the script to be served together with a cup of tee? Regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! Write the script yourself and when stuck come back here and ask a specific question!

Comment: What do you want. Bash or Batch-file?

Answer (score 2):

without knowing what particular position means, i have to leave this part for yourself. basically it's as easy as:

```
sed -n '1,/your particular position/p' s1 >> s3
cat s2 >> s3
```

i assume by merge you mean to append. it's better if you phrase your question better first.

Comment: Hi All,

My requirement here is to remove some specific text from a file and copy those contents and craete a new file.
input file is the filename where my filename is based on date and time, since I need to read today's file, im ignoring time and reading the file with *.

But while finding the string in those file is copying the text to the filename..I dont want my new copied file having those text..But currenly my output contains below. I want to remove that text (ie my file name)

Comment: @echo off

set Mth=%Date:~4,2%
set Day=%Date:~7,2%
set Yr=%Date:~10,4%
set TODAY=%Day%%Mth%%Yr%

ie my question is how to copy the contents in modifiedTGFile (the contents without those text Transaction Gateway Item Listing Creation Amount Seq Y: ) and the filename "Y:\NAS\EODReport\\"CAT Channels Audit Report_%TODAY%**.TXT\"


set inputfile=Y:\NAS\EODReport\\"CAT Channels Audit Report_%TODAY%**.TXT\"
FINDSTR  /V  "Transaction Gateway Item Listing Creation Amount Seq Y:" %inputfile%> modifiedTGFile.txt

Comment: @sree ah come on! spend your time writing your question then! after all you spent more time on writing comment, why not verbosity your question in the first place? apparently you want batch but why you tag bash? you are wasting people's time.